# accessing sql server using unixODBC's isql

Tags: sql-server, unix, rhel7, unixodbc, isql

I am trying to run a query on sql server (source) using isql on the client server.
Everything worked before the rhel6 to rhel7 upgrade on the client server. I am able to connect to sql server just not run any queries. I verified that all the drivers are there and none of the odbc files were changed. I can reproduce this in a different environment and it works fine.

```
$ export ODBCINI=/etc/alternatives/dmexpress/etc/odbc.ini
$ export ODBCSYSINI=/etc/alternatives/dmexpress/etc
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/etc/alternatives/dmexpress/ThirdParty/DataDirect/lib:/etc/alternatives/dmexpress/lib/:/opt/cloudera/impalaodbc/lib/64:/opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/lib/64
$ export PATH=/etc/alternatives/dmexpress/bin:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars:$PATH
$ isql -v Hadoop_Monitoring_Dev $user $password
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases
[60][DMExpress][ODBC 20101 driver]6091
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLExecute

$ cat /etc/alternatives/dmexpress/etc/odbc.ini
[ODBC]
InstallDir=/etc/alternatives/dmexpress/ThirdParty/DataDirect/lib
Trace           = Yes
TraceFile       = /tmp/odbc.trace

 [Hadoop_Monitoring_Dev]
Driver=/etc/alternatives/dmexpress/ThirdParty/DataDirect/lib/_Ssqls27.so
Description=DataDirect SQL Server Wire Protocol
AlwaysReportTriggerResults=0
AnsiNPW=1
ApplicationUsingThreads=1
AuthenticationMethod=1
BulkBinaryThreshold=32
BulkCharacterThreshold=-1
BulkLoadBatchSize=1024
BulkLoadOptions=0
ConnectionReset=0
ConnectionRetryCount=0
ConnectionRetryDelay=3
ConvWToUtf=1
Database=Hadoop_Monitoring_d10
DefaultLongDataBuffLen=1024
EnableBulkLoad=1
EnableQuotedIdentifiers=1
EncryptionMethod=0
FailoverGranularity=0
FailoverMode=0
FailoverPreconnect=0
FetchTSWTZasTimestamp=0
FetchTWFSasTime=1
GSSClient=native
HostName=dbhadoopmonitoringd10
LoadBalanceTimeout=0
LoadBalancing=0
LoginTimeout=15
LogonID=
MaxPoolSize=100
MinPoolSize=0
PacketSize=-1
Password=
Pooling=0
PortNumber=1460
QueryTimeout=0
ReportCodePageConversionErrors=0
SnapshotSerializable=0
ValidateServerCertificate=1
XMLDescribeType=-10
QEWSD=2457584

$ cat /etc/alternatives/dmexpress/etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC]
Trace           = Yes
TraceFile       = /tmp/odbcinst.trace


$ cat /etc/alternatives/dmexpress/etc/odbcinst.ini
# SQL Server driver.
[DataDirect SQL Server Wire Protocol]
Driver=/etc/alternatives/dmexpress/ThirdParty/DataDirect/lib/_Ssqls27.so
APILevel=1
ConnectFunctions=YYY
DriverODBCVer=3.52
FileUsage=0
HelpRootDirectory=/help
Setup=/etc/alternatives/dmexpress/ThirdParty/DataDirect/lib/_Ssqls27.so
SQLLevel=0
DMXODBCDRIVERMANAGER=NO
```

I did get a trace file that i called from odbcinst.ini but its not telling me much

```
$ cat odbcinst.trace
[ODBC][552119][1628599776.361874][__handles.c][460]
            Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                    Environment = 0x1dae750
[ODBC][552119][1628599776.362006][SQLAllocHandle.c][375]
            Entry:
                    Handle Type = 2
                    Input Handle = 0x1dae750
[ODBC][552119][1628599776.362088][SQLAllocHandle.c][493]
            Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                    Output Handle = 0x1daf050
[ODBC][552119][1628599776.362155][SQLConnect.c][3700]
            Entry:
                    Connection = 0x1daf050
                    Server Name = [Hadoop_Monitoring_Dev][length = 21 (SQL_NTS)]
                    User Name = [a00946r2][length = 8 (SQL_NTS)]
                    Authentication = [********][length = 8 (SQL_NTS)]
            UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'ISO8859-1' and UNICODE 'UCS-2LE'

            DIAG [2] [DMExpress][ODBC 20101 driver][Microsoft SQL Server]Changed database context to 'Hadoop_Monitoring_d10'.

            DIAG [2] [DMExpress][ODBC 20101 driver][Microsoft SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_english.

[ODBC][552119][1628599776.579031][SQLConnect.c][4273]
            Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO]
[ODBC][552119][1628599776.579131][SQLGetFunctions.c][151]
            Entry:
                    Connection = 0x1daf050
                    Id = SQLMoreResults
                    Supported = 0x607200
[ODBC][552119][1628599776.579187][SQLGetFunctions.c][186]
            Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                    Supported = 0x607200 -> 1
[ODBC][552119][1628599783.373310][SQLAllocHandle.c][540]
            Entry:
                    Handle Type = 3
                    Input Handle = 0x1daf050
[ODBC][552119][1628599783.373510][SQLAllocHandle.c][1081]
            Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                    Output Handle = 0x1e4c8c0
[ODBC][552119][1628599783.373587][SQLPrepare.c][196]
            Entry:
                    Statement = 0x1e4c8c0
                    SQL = [select count(*) from [Hadoop_Monitoring_d10].[dbo].[SCPT_EXEC]] 
[length = 62]
[ODBC][552119][1628599783.374670][SQLPrepare.c][371]
            Exit:[SQL_ERROR]
            DIAG [60] [DMExpress][ODBC 20101 driver]6091

[ODBC][552119][1628599783.374814][SQLError.c][352]
            Entry:
                    Statement = 0x1e4c8c0
                    SQLState = 0x7ffd0e17a2c0
                    Native = 0x7ffd0e17a2bc
                    Message Text = 0x7ffd0e17a2d0
                    Buffer Length = 500
                    Text Len Ptr = 0x7ffd0e17a2ba
[ODBC][552119][1628599783.374874][SQLError.c][389]
            Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                    SQLState = 60
                    Native = 0x7ffd0e17a2bc -> 6091
                    Message Text = [[DMExpress][ODBC 20101 driver]6091]
[ODBC][552119][1628599783.374941][SQLError.c][352]
            Entry:
                    Statement = 0x1e4c8c0
                    SQLState = 0x7ffd0e17a2c0
                    Native = 0x7ffd0e17a2bc
                    Message Text = 0x7ffd0e17a2d0
                    Buffer Length = 500
                    Text Len Ptr = 0x7ffd0e17a2ba
[ODBC][552119][1628599783.374992][SQLError.c][389]
            Exit:[SQL_NO_DATA]
[ODBC][552119][1628599783.375042][SQLError.c][434]
            Entry:
                    Connection = 0x1daf050
                    SQLState = 0x7ffd0e17a2c0
                    Native = 0x7ffd0e17a2bc
                    Message Text = 0x7ffd0e17a2d0
                    Buffer Length = 500
                    Text Len Ptr = 0x7ffd0e17a2ba
[ODBC][552119][1628599783.375105][SQLError.c][471]
            Exit:[SQL_NO_DATA]
[ODBC][552119][1628599783.375157][SQLError.c][514]
            Entry:
                    Environment = 0x1dae750
                    SQLState = 0x7ffd0e17a2c0
                    Native = 0x7ffd0e17a2bc
                    Message Text = 0x7ffd0e17a2d0
                    Buffer Length = 500
                    Text Len Ptr = 0x7ffd0e17a2ba
[ODBC][552119][1628599783.375205][SQLError.c][551]
            Exit:[SQL_NO_DATA]
[ODBC][552119][1628599783.375276][SQLFreeStmt.c][144]
            Entry:
                    Statement = 0x1e4c8c0
                    Option = 1
[ODBC][552119][1628599783.375331][SQLFreeHandle.c][381]
            Entry:
                    Handle Type = 3
                    Input Handle = 0x1e4c8c0
[ODBC][552119][1628599783.375415][SQLFreeHandle.c][491]
            Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [official ODBC 17 driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server#redhat17) instead of a third party driver?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning we do have unixODBC installed

Comment: Have you installed `msodbcsql17`? Doesn't seem referenced in your .ini files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with licensing. I had to make odbc.ini writable so it could write
qewsd
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/what-does-qewsd-mean-odbcini-file